weird window switching behavior and "current locus from *Occur*"
I'm seeing some weird behavior that seems related to Occur and perhaps next-error-follow-minor-mode. Here's the workflow:

I have a frame with two windows side-by-side.
I switch from one to the other (I happen to use ace-window for that, but I don't think that's relevant here).
When I do, the starting buffer changes, and the minibuffer gives me a Current locus from *Occur* message.

I don't want the starting buffer to change; I want it to stay so I can refer to it.
What's strange is that I don't seem to have any Occur buffers right now. I do have next-error-follow-minor-mode enabled, but I would expect that to do nothing when there's no *Occur* or similar kind of buffer open.
What is causing this behavior? It seems like something related to next-error-follow-minor-mode is sticking around too long?
